# Editable OData Service using .NET with Dynamic EDM Model

Tags: c#, .net, odata

I have successfully used [this example](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApiCore/DynamicEdmModelCreation) to create a read only OData service with a dynamic model.

I would like to extend with an Editable OData service.

Are there any open source examples of an editable OData services with a dynamic model using .NET?

Any recommendation on an approach?

Comment: Did you look at the other samples? https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApiCore

Comment: Yes I have looked at the other samples and none have an editable service using dynamic data

Comment: Isn't editing just reading and existing value, changing, and then writing back?